# Hold UIPickerViewDelegate method from being triggered for couple of seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have to append name of a city at the end of base API before calling it. I choose `UIPickerView` to select desired city but when scrolling rows for required city, the scroll pause (as you expect when scrolling through a long list) triggers the following `UIPickerViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

To the point, it makes api call for wrong city. Is there any other way / method to get scroll selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other method that the `UIPickerViewDelegate` calls that would provide you with the the selected row. However, there are alternative ways of achieving the effect you are looking for.

Perhaps the simplest thing you could do is add a `UIToolbar`, place it directly above your `UIPicker` and add a button that displays "Select" (or whatever word you feel is appropriate). When the user is done with their scrolling and actually on the desired city they can press the button. At that point you can access which index the `UIPicker` is on with:

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Then you can perform your API request and it will be with the correct city!

Comment: Hello @dunkmann00, I am little confused on how to do that. Will let you know if it works

Comment: I used a bar button and created IB Action for using method : `- (IBAction)chooseCurrency:(id)sender`
I am lost at figuring how to use :
`- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component`
method to access the index of UIPicker. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Abdkar In the method you attached the IB Action to, `- (IBAction)chooseCurrency:(id)sender`, call your UIPickerView's `- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component` with a component of 0 (assuming there is only 1 component) and the return value will be the current row of the UIPickerView.

Comment: @Abdkar Any luck with this?

Comment: Yay!
I was lost and gave it a break. Tried again and it works!! Thanks a lot!!